# How can I run something when all extensions are available?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to understand what is safe vs. not safe with respect to the Eclipse plugin lifecycle.

**Background**

Something in the Eclipse/RCP/OSGI framework allows for circular dependencies between bundles by allowing bundles to provide extension points. If bundle *X* provides an extension point, Bundle *Y* may both depend on bundle *X*, and provide an extension that implements an interface or extends a class known to *X*, and make that extension available to bundle *X*.

Then there's the promise of activators: as far as I understand, it is promised that your activator's `start(BundleContext)` method will be called before any class in your bundle is made available to any other bundle, and that your dependencies' `start(...)` methods will have been called before yours.

**Limitations/Possible Contradictions**

Now, I'm ready to describe my conundrum: I would like to retrieve all the providers of a specific extension point as soon as possible; the easy way to do this would appear to be in the activator of my bundle.

However, if what I've described about the promises that the Eclipse/RCP/OSGI framework makes is true, then I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be possible for me to do that during activation:

Either (1) I'll have a reference to classes provided by one of my dependencies before their `start(...)` method has been called, or (2) My dependency's `start(...)` method will have to be called before mine, or (3) No violations will occur, but I'll retrieve zero extensions because the plugins that depend on me couldn't be started before me, so their implementations of my extension point are not yet available.

**Why I Need Extensions at Startup**

My challenge is that I need to load some data ASAP after the startup of my plugin, but I need to ensure that my extensions are loaded first, because the extensions in question are extensions to the data format of the data that I need to load; if I load the data first, it fails or becomes corrupted.

I'm also wondering whether my picture of the Eclipse plugin lifecycle is correct, because, despite searching for discussions of the plugin lifecycle, I haven't come across any warnings about its limitations; I'm fairly certain it must be possible to do things wrong and create serious problems, and I'd like to understand under what circumstances things would go wrong so I can avoid creating problems.

Answer (score 1):

The extension point registry accessed by the `IExtensionRegistry` interface will tell you about extension points without starting any of the plugins involved.

```
IExtensionRegistry extReg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
```

In the registry for an extension point you will have a number of `IConfigurationElement` entries describing the individual extensions declared by plugins. It is only when you call the `createExecutableExtension` method of this interface that the the contributing plugin is started.

Note: A plugin's activator `start` method is not normally run until Eclipse needs to run some other code in the plugin - it does not run at Eclipse startup unless you force it too.

Comment: I don't actually need my bundle to be loaded at Eclipse startup...but I do need loading of my bundle to trigger the loading of the extensions for a particular extension point, and after the full set of extensions has loaded, I then need to load my data. For the reasons outlined above, I doubt this is safe to do in my `start` method; is there a safe way from the `start` method to request that something be run after the `start` method has finished, so that I can safely retrieve the extensions?

Comment: The start method would be fine except that, as I say, it normally is not run until something else in the plugin is used. All the information in the extension registry is available all the time.

Comment: But, if I ask for the extensions in my start method, aren't I potentially breaking the framework somehow? Because the start method of the other plugins is supposed to come after mine finishes, and before any of their classes are made available to me, as far as I understand.

Comment: No, start methods don't run one after another. If your start method happens to cause another plugin to start its start method will run while your start method is running - this is absolutely normal.

Comment: Ah...so it's just unsafe to assume any of your dependencies has reached its "ready" state, if it requires some sort of preparation? If I retrieve the extensions, I have no guarantee that the bundle(s) they come from have finished startup, just as those bundles that rely on me, during their start methods, have no guarantee that I have finished my startup, unless we've agreed upon some handshake to indicate our readiness to eachother?

Comment: If the start methods do everything synchronously there is no problem. If they just start something which does not finish until later you will have to deal with that.

Comment: Well, if my `start` method in bundle `X` refers to an extension provided by bundle `Y`, and the `start` method of bundle `Y` refers to something provided by bundle `X`, then we must either have a deadlock, a stack overflow, or one of the bundles must make some of its contained classes available to the other before its own `start` method finishes.